# bash for loop variable not changing

Tags: bash, sed, for

I am iterating over indexes which are used to create data file id's. When I create the file name (data_file) and echo it, it prints properly, but when I try to sed that variable into the desired files it only places the first index.

```
# copy files
cp student_t_sampler.c student_t_sampler_copy.c
cp post_process.py post_process_copy.py

run_mcmc=1

n_samples=1000
n_thin=100
nu=3.
mu=1.
sig=1.
start_data_file=\"data_file
end_data_file=.txt\"
seed=1
alpha=1.


for i in "10. 1" "1. 2" "0.1 3" "0.01 4"; do # i is alpha, num
    IFS=' ' read -a myarray <<< "$i"
    alpha=${myarray[0]}
    num=${myarray[1]}

    data_file=$start_data_file$num$end_data_file
    echo $data_file
    if [ $run_mcmc == 1 ]; then 

        sed -i "s/nnn/$n_samples/g" student_t_sampler_copy.c # set number of samples, 1000
        sed -i "s/ttt/$n_thin/g" student_t_sampler_copy.c # set thinning, 5
        sed -i "s/nununu/$nu/g" student_t_sampler_copy.c # set nu
        sed -i "s/mumumu/$mu/g" student_t_sampler_copy.c # set mu
        sed -i "s/sigsigsig/$sig/g" student_t_sampler_copy.c # set sig
        sed -i "s/fff/$data_file/g" student_t_sampler_copy.c # data file
        sed -i "s/sss/$seed/g" student_t_sampler_copy.c # set seed
        sed -i "s/aaa/$alpha/g" student_t_sampler_copy.c # set alpha

        make ./student_t_sampler_copy 
        ./student_t_sampler_copy 
    fi

    n_bins=100
    # echo "$data_file"
    sed -i "s/fff/$data_file/g" post_process_copy.py # set data file in python
    sed -i "s/bbb/$n_bins/g" post_process_copy.py # set number of bins
    sed -i "s/aaa/$alpha/g" post_process_copy.py # set set in plot title
    sed -i "s/iii/$num/g" post_process_copy.py # set set in plot title

    python post_process_copy.py 
done

wait # wait for all processes to finish
```

The output is as follows

```
"data_file1.txt"
gcc -I/usr/include -L/usr/local/lib  student_t_sampler_copy.c -o                    student_t_sampler_copy -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
"data_file2.txt"
gcc -I/usr/include -L/usr/local/lib  student_t_sampler_copy.c -o student_t_sampler_copy -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
"data_file3.txt"
gcc -I/usr/include -L/usr/local/lib  student_t_sampler_copy.c -o student_t_sampler_copy -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
"data_file4.txt"
gcc -I/usr/include -L/usr/local/lib  student_t_sampler_copy.c -o    student_t_sampler_copy -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

So even though it echos the correct data file, both python and c only receive data_file1.txt

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by "both python and c only receive data_file1.txt"

Comment: why run `sed` so many times? `sed` can take multiple `-e` options, and/or you can have multiple commands in a quoted `sed` script separated by semi-colons or newlines.  e.g. `sed -i " s/nnn/$n_samples/g; s/ttt/$n_thin/g; ..." student_t_sampler_copy.c`.   BTW, you would be **much** better off by just improving both `student_t_sampler.c` and `post_process.py` so that they took command-line arguments for the variables you're changing - using `sed` as a substitute for `getopt` is a lot more complicated and prone to mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're producing the `student_t_sampler_copy.c` from the template `student_t_sampler.c` at the start of the script and outside the loop that updates the copy, therefore you're only updating the copy in the first iteration of the loop, and all of the other iterations there's nothing else to change. You have to copy the file within the loop (immediately after the `for`).